# Why does `git cherry-pick --allow-empty` have no effect?

Tags: git

If I cherry-pick a commit which makes no changes, but I want it to commit anyways (so that the audit trail of commits is consistent with another project), I get the message:

```
$ git cherry-pick 696abcb
...
nothing to commit, working directory clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

     git commit --allow-empty
```

According to the man pages, I can use cherry-pick with `--allow-empty`. But this results in the same message:

```
$ git cherry-pick --allow-empty 696abcb
```

(same message as above)

Is this a bug? Am I completely misunderstanding the point of this option?

Comment: The `--allow-empty` flag is really for use in cherry-picking a *range* of commits. The sequencer would omit the empty commits in that range, without the flag. I agree that it does not work as well as it should, though.

Comment: what is an API flaw....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Git 2.22 (Q2 2019), you won't have to run `git commit --allow-empty`.
"`git cherry-pick --options A..B`", after giving control back to the user to ask help resolving a conflicted step, did not honor the options it originally received, which has been corrected.

See [commit 6860ce5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6860ce5d8e461e5997029abe73c39590d349cef9), [commit 36b0503](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36b0503a19c777b57805aa26aabd77f99dbf91b7), [commit f59199d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f59199d5faac328becafdb60507ca4c05bdd9a95) (13 Mar 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d2dba18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2dba18ced8e4939a3cd135998c54874ce73adc1), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `cherry-pick --continue`: remember options
>
> Remember `--allow-empty`, `--allow-empty-message` and `--keep-redundant-commits` when cherry-pick stops for a conflict resolution.

Comment: `--keep-redundant-commits` made the difference for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's nothing to cherry-pick, there's no work that can be done.  The only possible thing that you could do is create an empty *commit*.  It's *not* instructing you to run `git cherry-pick --allow-empty`, instead it's instructing you to run:

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

Note that's the *commit* command.  git will not, by default, create commits with no changes in them.

(git questions the value of creating an empty commit, just to include a commit message in your history - as do I, to be frank - but if you need it for auditing, then this is the way to do it.)

Comment: the question is correct, just the explanation `Since there's nothing to cherry-pick, there's no work that can be done.` is wrong. You could be cherry-picking a commit that adds a file (like `.gikeep`): there is work that can be done.  `git cherry-pick --allow-empty sha` could cherry-pick that "empty" commit, but the API designers understood that cherry-pick of an empty commit, even explicitly stating "--allow-empty" is the same as doing nothing....

Comment: the question is correct, just the explanation `Since there's nothing to cherry-pick, there's no work that can be done.` is wrong. You could be cherry-picking a commit that adds a file (like `.gikeep`): there is work that can be done.  `git cherry-pick --allow-empty sha` could cherry-pick that "empty" commit, but the API designers understood that cherry-pick of an empty commit, even explicitly stating "--allow-empty" is the same as doing nothing....

Comment: (I meant the "answer")

Comment: No, this question is not about _cherry-picking_ an "empty" commit.  In this case the commit was _not_ empty, but it had already been applied (via a different cherry-pick, or a merge, etc).  So there is nothing to do, and cherry-pick has stopped.  If you still want to create an empty _commit_ then you can run `git commit --allow-empty` (not _`cherry-pick`_) at this point.