# git rebase --continue still sees conflicts, git status tells me there are none

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am running a fairly complex rebase that had gone well for the last few commits. I fixed a very small conflict and somehow got stuck in limbo --

```
    ╰─$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 99e642b
You are currently rebasing branch 'Vince_issue_157' on '99e642b'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean

    ╰─$ git rebase --continue Applying: RM debugger No changes - did you forget to use git add?
```

Shouldn't those two be contradictions? How can I figure out what git doesnt like?

---

Quick reflog output if that raises any red flags

```
dc04ac4 (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: rebase: improve warning
f97482a HEAD@{1}: rebase: incomplete test for new warning
e73be23 HEAD@{2}: rebase: warning (that needs tweak) on default lang with no translation problem
99e642b (upstream/master, master) HEAD@{3}: rebase: checkout master
5d8b393 (origin/Vince_issue_157, Vince_issue_157) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to Vince_issue_157
99e642b (upstream/master, master) HEAD@{5}: reset: moving to upstream/master
```

Comment: *"How can I figure out what git doesnt like?"* Well, you might need to add some more of your understanding of the situation because Git gave the message that there are *"No changes" (nothing modified/added/removed/conflicting and even unknown/other) so there is nothing to commit (so skip the commit in that rebase after merge resolution [this is common] or do an empty commit [most often useless, see `--allow-empty` for `git commit`]. Git is just trying to tell you that there are no changes for the commit you're trying to do (while rebasing after conflict resolution). See as well `git rerere`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick recap:  The conflicts occurred while Git was trying to copy an existing commit whose subject line is:

```
RM debugger
```

That is, during `git rebase`, which works by copying some series of commits to new-and-improved commits that do the same thing as the originals except for some improvement (e.g., being on a different starting base commit), Git tried to copy that commit, and got some merge conflicts.  So rebase stopped with `RM debugger` not yet applied.

You then did some work in your index-and-work-tree to resolve these conflicts, including `git add` at the end.  Then you ran `git rebase --continue`.

This message:

> ```
> $ git rebase --continue
> Applying: RM debugger
> No changes - did you forget to use git add?
> ```

does not mean there are *conflicts*.  It means that the source code in your index now, ready to be committed as the new-and-improved copy of `RM debugger`, is *exactly the same* as the source code in your existing commit `dc04ac4` (`improve warning`), which itself is a copy of some older commit whose subject was already `improve warning`.

Git dislikes making commits that repeat the same source code.  (Git calls these *empty commits*, although they're not empty at all, they're just immediate repeats.)  It dislikes this so much that `git rebase` refuses to do it at all by default, including after you have resolved any conflicts.

This is sometimes a sign that you resolved the conflict the wrong way: that you accidentally dropped your change.  But maybe that *is* the right thing to do.

If the correct thing to do at this point is to *drop* the original commit entirely—if there's no change needed now because the new base for the new and improved commits doesn't need any fixing—just run:

```
git rebase --skip
```

to tell Git: *This commit shouldn't be copied after all.*

If you really want the empty commit, you can manually commit it yourself, using `git commit --allow-empty`, then use `git rebase --continue` to proceed.

Comment: I wonder if `git rebase` wouldn't need an `--allow-empty` option, like `cherry-pick` does (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---allow-empty), knowing that `cherry-pick` now actually use it (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55884504/6309)

Comment: @VonC: It probably should. All of the sequencer things are a little weird, though, since there's start state, in-process state, resume state, etc., that might all not match: should you be able to *cancel* a `--keep-empty`, for instance?

Comment: Possibly through `git rebase --edit-todo`. But yes, the all [sequencer.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6860ce5d8e461e5997029abe73c39590d349cef9/sequencer.c) is convoluted to say the least. I like [this comment](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6860ce5d8e461e5997029abe73c39590d349cef9/sequencer.c#L4081-L4085): "This means it is possible to cherry-pick in the middle of a cherry-pick sequence"! Mind blown.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that there are **no changes** to be applied for this revision. Probably you want to do `git rebase --skip`